# R: rvest - is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying out the "new" Rvest package from Hadley Wickham.

I've used it in the past, so I'd expected that everything run smoothly.

However, I keep seen this error:

```
> TV_Audio_Video_Marca <- read_html(page_source[[1]], encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
Error: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xCD 0x20 0x53 0x2E [9]
```

As you see in the code, I've use encoding: `ISO-8859-1`. Before that I was using "UTF-8", but function `guess_encoding(page_source[[1]])` says that the encoding is: `ISO-8859-1`. I've tried with all the options provided by `guess_encoding` but none worked.

What is the problem?

My code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
#start RSelenium
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("http://www.linio.com.pe/tv-audio-y-video/televisores/")

#scroll down 5 times, waiting for the page to load at each time
for(i in 1:5){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
  Sys.sleep(3)    
}

#get the page html
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()

#parse it

TV_Audio_Video_Marca <- read_html(page_source[[1]], encoding = "UTF-16LE")
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've googled for "How to now the encoding of a web page?".

Found out this Makrup Validation Tool from W3C, but It wasn't of great help:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.w3.org/2003/10/empty/emptydoc.html

Comment: Try: `TV_Audio_Video_Marca <- read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]], to="UTF-8"), encoding = "utf8")`

Comment: Works, please post a complete answer with an explanation for iconv(), and it's use in this case. The documentation did not mention this "trick", or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the page source, they claim to be using UTF-8 encoding:

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> ```

So, the question is, are they really using a different enough encoding we need to worry about, or can we just convert to utf-8, guessing that any errors will be negligible?

If you are happy with a quick and dirty approach, and some potential mojibake, you can just force utf-8 using `iconv`:

```
TV_Audio_Video_Marca <- read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]], to = "UTF-8"), encoding = "utf8")
```

In general, this is a bad idea - better to specify the encoding it's from. In this case, maybe the error is theirs, so this quick and dirty approach might be ok.

Comment: Is there a tool to validate encoding? As you say they say the use "utf-8", but for example Rvest does not recognize it. I see the page in Spanish and everything is Ok. But how to tell "Are they really using "utf-8"?

Comment: you did the right thing, as far as I can tell the error is on the websites side. If you do want to be sure you have it correct, `read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]], from = "ISO-8859-1", to = "UTF-8"), encoding = "utf8")` is explicit