# rvest read_html input is not proper UTF-8 encoding error

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to debug a web scraper and I'm running into an encoding issue using Hadley's `rvest` package.

As a reproducible example, consider the following two links:

```
library(rvest)

## This works:
read_html("http://clasificadosonline.com/UDRealEstateDetail.asp?ID=4234361")

## This gives me an error:
read_html("http://clasificadosonline.com/UDRealEstateDetail.asp?ID=4252734")
```

First link:

```
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n\r\n\t\r\nif (screen.width <= 480) {\r\n\tdocument.location = "http://www.clasificado ...
[2] <body>\n<br><link href="StylesClas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">\n<!-- Google Tag Manager --><noscript><iframe src="//w ...
```

Second link:

```
> read_html("http://clasificadosonline.com/UDRealEstateDetail.asp?ID=4252734")
Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xDA 0x4C 0x54 0x49 [9]
```

Inspecting the HTML for **BOTH** pages, and I see the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

**Why does one work, but the other doesn't?**

I have tried wrapping `x` in `read_html()` with `iconv()` as shown in the following related questions and it did not work:

1. [R: rvest - is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833894/r-rvest-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding)
2. [encoding error with read_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290452/encoding-error-with-read-html)

EDIT:

I am using the following packages:

- `rvest_0.3.2`
- `xml2_1.2.0`
- `httr_1.3.1`

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
read_html("http://clasificadosonline.com/UDRealEstateDetail.asp?ID=4252734",
    encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

Since that is what the document says. The problem with putting that data in the meta tag is that R needs to be able to read the file in order to read that tag, but if it doesn't have the right encoding, it can't read the file.

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick for me. I understand why you have the explicit `encoding="iso-8859-1"` part, but if you don't mind me asking, why is the `b<-` necessary?

Comment: @Ray. Oops, that was left over from testing. It's not necessary. I've removed it.